# Form submit fails in Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail

Tags: forms, html-email

I am in receipt of an forwarded email that has a form to be filled & submitted for a course/event registration. The form has a studentId, emailId, mobileNo, password, Confirm password  fields & a submit button.

On Gmail, I fill in details & submit, nothing happens.
In yahoo, as I type the password (after typing other fields), I get a popup that says that the form is not being submitted to yahoo & yahoo never asks password. I do a OK on the popup & submit the form, nothing happens
In hotmail, as I try to type in characters in any of the above fields the cursor disappears, so nothing to submit.

A 'view source' of the page does not show a 'form' element that I was expecting. When I do a inspect element I am able to see the static labels against each of the fields above though no form element. See a lot of tr, td wrapped in table/tbody.

I have tried reading various forums, they seem to mention that having such forms in html emails is a bad idea & better option is to provide a link. None of them say that it will not work on gmail or yahoo.

This mails with the form has been sent to many people & some of them at least have been able to submit. I am just unable to figure out the reason for the failure of the submit. I have tried IE, Mozilla & Chrome.

Any views on what the solution to the problem would be very helpful.

Comment: Forms are definitely a bad idea if you are trying to support the most emial clients (including hotmail(outlook.com) as you suggested): https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/

Comment: Agreed but I have been sent this email & I am not in a position to ask them to send it differently :-( I am wondering how some of the others have been able to successfully able to submit. BTW, I had read a similar  article to one pointed out by you. It actually says forms work in yahoo mail

Answer (score 0):

On some newer email readers the form tag is stripped out because of security issues. It's better to have the form on the Internet and a link to it from the email document.